# Why can't gcc deduce the return value type after parsing the first return clause?

Tags: c++, return, c++20, initializer-list, type-deduction

Why this code is not valid?

```
auto f() {
  if (true) return 0;
  return {};
}
```

After parsing `0`, I think gcc should know that the return type of function `f` was `int`, but it still interpret the `{}` as the `initializer_list` when parsing the final return clause, why?

Comment: Even if that code is valid, it certainly is confusing for human readers. And if you generate such C++ code, you could improve the generator. At last [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) is [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html). You are allowed to improve it

Comment: brace-enclosed lists does not have a type, and in deduced context they are always `std::initializer_list`s. Just because something could work doesn't mean it's already been implemented or that it's a good idea. This looks pretty useless to me.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: There are several confusing valid/legal codes. It is not a bug of gcc, so nothing to change here. The question is valid (even if little ambiguity between "Which part of standard prohibit such construct?" and "Why does standard prohibit such construct?").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [function#Return_type_deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Return_type_deduction)

> if there are multiple return statements, they must all deduce to the same type

and

> If the return statement uses a brace-init-list, deduction is not allowed:

Which prohibit such construct.

> Once a return statement has been seen in a function, the return type deduced from that statement can be used in the rest of the function, including in other return statements.

only allows to reuse the function recursively.

Comment: What does *can be used* refer to in the last quote? Reading it out of context here it really sounds like the code in the question should be ok.

Comment: @super: It is to allow recursive calls mainly `auto fact(int n) { if (n < 2) return 1;
  return n * fact(n - 1);
}` is valid. (whereas `auto fact(int n) {
  if (n >= 2) return n * fact(n - 1);
  return 1;}` isn't). Once we encounter first return, we might assumes the return type, but others rules still apply: consistent return type and no `return {..}`.